# Vaadin 14: Trying to open Page in background from Dialog while keeping the dialog opened

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a dialogue box that is:

1. Draggable
2. Modal

**Requirement:**

*I have a requirement where I don't need to close my dialogue and have to load the different pages in the background on the selection of data from the grid that is on Dialogue.*

**What did I do:**
I know how to open the page in the background with the help of a de-attached listener.

```
vehicleInfoPopUpView.addDetachListener(e -> {

        UI.getCurrent().navigate(AssignmentPageContainer.class,
            String.valueOf(vehicleInfoPopUpView.getCanFileNumber()));
    });
```

The above code (in the parent page) loads/opens a new page but to do this I have to close my dialogue box (which I don't have to do, I have to keep the dialogue box open).

**I cannot find any resource that tells me How to load/open a new page in the background from the dialogue box without closing it**

Any small help! Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What did you try so far? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli explained my situation.

Answer (score 10):

First of all: **Don't.**

Keeping a *modal* dialog open whilst navigating to a different page/route makes no UX sense. A *modal* window means you cannot interact with the background.

Just call `UI.getCurrent().navigate(AssignmentPageContainer.class)` directly (outside of detach listener) to open the view based on the selection. The user will open the dialog again himself, if he will want to. You can trigger this on some button click.

---

Secondly, as a workaround you could store the state of the dialog in a `@UIScoped` service and open & reinitialize the dialog f.e. in the `afterNavigation` method.